# Event to detect ActiveSelf

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a listener event to detect if an object is set to inactive from active state or to active from inactive state? I do not want to add it in Update as there will be multiple calls and it would affect my game's performance. So is there an alternative for this?

```
    public GameObject Go_1;
    public GameObject Go_2;

    void Update () {
        if (Go_1.activeSelf) {

        } else if (Go_2.activeSelf) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement something using the `Update` method like e.g.

```
public class ActiveSelfWatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<ActiveSelfProvider, bool> _lastActiveSelfState = new Dictionary<ActiveSelfProvider, bool>();

    private void OnObjectBecameActive(GameObject obj)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{obj.name} became active!", this);
    }

    private void OnObjectBecameInactive(GameObject obj)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{obj.name} became inactive!", this);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Iterate through all registered instances of ActiveSelfProvider
        foreach(var provider in ActiveSelfProvider.Instances)
        {
            // pre-cache the GameObject reference
            var obj = provider.gameObject;
            // pre-cache the current activeSelf state
            var currentActive = obj.activeSelf;

            if(!_lastActiveSelfState.TryGetValue(provider))
            {
                // we don't know this provider until now 

                // TODO here you have to decide whether you want to call the events now once for this provider or not
                // TODO otherwise it is only called for providers you already know and changed their state
            }

            if(currentActive != _lastActiveSelfState[provider])
            {
                // the state is not the one we stored for this instance
                // => it changed its states since the last frame

                // Call the according "event"
                if(currentActive)
                {
                    OnObjectBecameActive(obj);
                }
                else
                {
                    OnObjectBecameInactive(obj);
                }
            }

            // store the current value
            _lastActiveSelfState[provider] = currentActive;
        }
    }
}
```

This is your watcher class you currently already have anyway.

Then on all the objects you want to be able to watch you use

```
public class ActiveSelfProvider : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly HashSet<ActiveSelfProvider> instances = new HashSet<ActiveSelfProvider>();
    public static HashSet<ActiveSelfProvider> Instances => new HashSet<ActiveSelfProvider>(instances);

    private void Awake()
    {
        // register your self to the existing instances
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // remove yourself from the existing instances
        instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

If this is "efficient enough" for you use case you would have to test ;)

---

If you want to go super fancy, someone once made a [Transform Interceptor](https://github.com/handzlikchris/Unity.TransformSetterInterceptor) .. a quite nasty hack which on compile time overrules parts of the Unity built-in `Transform` property setters to hook in callbacks.

One probably could create something like this also for `SetActive` ;)

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Oh WOW! Thank you I shall try this. It will take me some time to understand and definitely Unity should see this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try with [OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) and [OnDisable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html).

```
// Implement OnDisable and OnEnable script functions.
// These functions will be called when the attached GameObject
// is toggled.
// This example also supports the Editor.  The Update function
// will be called, for example, when the position of the
// GameObject is changed.

using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PrintOnOff : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log("PrintOnDisable: script was disabled");
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("PrintOnEnable: script was enabled");
    }

    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Update");
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: But this I have to add specifically on gameObject right? I have created a script as a parent GameObject and adding all the SetActive gameObjects to this. So how do I achieve that with a listener? Also your script only works if the script is enabled/disabled, not when I disable the gameObject

Comment: Yes, this script needs to be placed on a GameObject. No, it will also be called when the GO is disabled. And I don't get the "I've created a script as a parent...this" can you refrase it please?

Comment: To extend @Naik 's comment: This is actually also only tracking `activeInHierarchy` not `activeSelf` ;) `OnEnable` is only called if both GameObject is active in Hierarchy and the component is enebled .. `OnDisable` is also called when only the component is disabled which seems not what OP wants

Comment: @derHugo from the docs: OnEnable or OnDisable are called as the GameObject received SetActive(true) or SetActive(false). And also for activeSelf: This returns the local active state of this GameObject, which is set using GameObject.SetActive. PS: But yes, activeInHierarchy is not contempled.

Comment: @derHugo exactly my point. Can I create a single script and add all gameObjects to that script like how I showed in my question, and then add listener to the same script for each gameObject so that a function is called when it is set to active/inactive.

Comment: no the behavior I am used to is `OnEnable` is only called if the component is enabled and `SetActive(true)` makes the gameobject active in the Hierarchy .. it is not called if e.g. a parent is still inactive ;) .. @Naik there is no built-in event for that ... you could build a watcher component but it will not be very performant ^^

Comment: @derHugo okay that is sad. :( I guess I have to use Update() to check for now.